# Repeat one python script with different inputs 1 to 100

Tags: python

I have python script a.py and it takes integer input
I want to repeat this script with different input integers from 1 to 10.
Usually I do create a1.py to a10.py with integer hard-corded but i want to run them without creating a1.py to a10.py

Edit:

I have script test.py

```
import sys
count = sys.argv[1]
print(count)
```

#I use this count value as an input for running further script

I want to run python test.py 2 after python test.py 1 finishes and so on.
So I naively use this command:
python test.py 1 && python test.py 2 && python test.py 3 && and so on... up to python test.py 10

Is there any short way to write this long command.

Comment: You can use command line arguments. https://realpython.com/python-command-line-arguments/

Comment: Or make it a function and run in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sys.argv` for getting parameters.
And run the file passing the parameter to the function  `python my_file.py 10`.

```
import sys


def run_range():
    count = sys.argv[1]
    for i in range(int(count)):
        print(i)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_range()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to this:

```py
def myFunc(x):
    print(f"HALLO {x}")

for x in range(0, 11):
    myFunc(x)
```

Comment: my python script is memory intensive. Hence, I cannot keep running all in one python script by looping.